# XAML Collection Databinding

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am working on simple card game, could you please enlight how to instantiate collection and add something to it.

Here is my basic Card class and Cards class that contains ObservableList of Cards

```
class Card
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

class Cards
{
    public ObservableCollection<Card> CardCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my XAML, note that binding is OK but the list is empty I have no idea how to add items on list.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:Cards x:Name="Cards"></local:Cards>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <TextBlock Text="Cards"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI"
               FontSize="42"></TextBlock>
    <ListView Margin="10,60,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding CardCollection}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="50" Background="White">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do like this.

```
class Cards
{
    private ObservableCollection<Card> _CardCollection = new ObservableCollection<Card>();

    public  ObservableCollection<Card> CardCollection
    {
        get
        { 
            return _CardCollection;
        }

        set
        {
              _CardCollection=value;
              OnPropertyChanged("CardCollection");  //Implement property changed event  
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You may have to implement `propertychanged` event if you want the `ListView` to reflect changes in `ObservableCollection` you have binded.

Edit: You can Add and Remove items from `ObservableCollection` from `Add()` and `Remove()` methods. Take a look at this page for all the methods available for `ObservableCollection` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

You can add an item to the collection here like this

```
CardCollection.Add(new Card{Name="Ace of spades"});
```

Edit 2:

Yes you can use implement the ICommand Interface and bind a command to your controls. Take a look at this http://www.markwithall.com/programming/2013/03/01/worlds-simplest-csharp-wpf-mvvm-example.html

If you just want to get the instance binded to your XAML. You can access it like this in your `Mainpage.xaml.cs`

```
var bind = (Cards)DataContext;
```

You can get binded collection like this `bind.CardCollection`

Comment: While the controll is rendered there is a new instance created. Could you please tell me how to get access to this instance of colection? I mean how to add and remove elements in code-behind.

Comment: I know Add and Remove methods. What I meant is - Classes are located in Card.cs file and if I want to hendle events such as Click those events are located in MainPage.xaml.cs file. How can I acces my collection from code behind when it is instantiated by XAML? Should I use Command structure?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
Collection property must be instatiated before it can be used.
I have added it in constructor of my Cards class

```
class Cards
{
    public ObservableCollection<Card> CardCollection { get; set; }

    public Cards()
    {
        CardCollection = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    }
}
```